# Python regular expression

Tags: python, regex

There is one problem bother me for a long time.

In Python, the regex always match the longest string in the content.

For example, the content is below:

```
<test> A <br> B <br>
```

If I use the regex `re.compile('/<test/>(\w\s)+/<br/>')`, python match longest string which means `<test> A <br> B <br>`

How can I match the shortest string which is `<test> A <br>` ?

Thanks for your reading and reply.

Comment: Add a `?` to your `+` to make it non-greedy (the it does not **always** match the longest string in the content)

Comment: Hi, I think that adding ? is not a good way to solve this problem. Because ? means 0 or 1 time(s), it's will match the longest string in this simple cause and other more complex cause, too. Thanks for your reply.

Comment: @Jimmy the `?` has more than one meaning in regex and if you put it after a quantifier, then it does mean "Make this quantifier non-greedy"

Comment: Oh, I know what you mean, I will try later. I misunderstood your meaning. Sorry for that.

Comment: A universal useful principle in life is that it's highly informative to study a documentation before bumping into grotesquely-basic questions. A second useful principle on SO is that it's often very informative to make a search, particularly for questions asked one million times.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your regex looks really strange. I think you mean:

```
re.compile('/<test>[\w\s]+<br>/')
```

And in that case you can make it 'non-greedy' using a question mark:

```
re.compile('/<test>[\w\s]+?<br>/')
```

Comment: Thank you very much, it's goes very well.

Comment: @Dan Why the two ``/`` ? There's no tag PHP. - I wonder why ``[\w\s]+?`` instead of ``.+?`` , also, but it's Jimmy that must answer.

Answer (score 3):

From [the docs](http://docs.python.org/library/re.html):

> `*?`, `+?`, `??`
>       The `'*'`, `'+'`, and `'?'` qualifiers are all greedy; they match as much text as possible. Sometimes this behaviour isn’t desired; if the RE `<.*>` is matched against `'<H1>title</H1>'`, it will match the entire string, and not just `'<H1>'`. Adding `'?'` after the qualifier makes it perform the match in non-greedy or minimal fashion; as few characters as possible will be matched. Using `.*?` in the previous expression will match only `'<H1>'`.

But you shouldn't be using regular expressions for XML.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use non-greedy matching, which can be found in the manual (just search for non-greedy):

[Regular expressions - Python documentation](http://docs.python.org/library/re.html)

In your case, I believe the correct regex would be: `re.compile('/<test/>(\w\s)+?/<br/>')`

Comment: I didn't downvote, but I assume because you adopted the wrong regex from the OP, `(\w\s)+?` is wrong, should be `[\w\s]+?`

Comment: Of course not. Elaborating would mean that their argument could be picked apart and they'd be made to look like a fool. Easier to just hit and run.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams, sorry, everyone is able to cast every vote he wants for every reason he likes, I am not able to explain every vote on SO and belief me, there are a lot of votes I don't understand.

Comment: Ok, let's drop the discussion, I was just curious what was the reason. @stema: Maybe so, I didn't focus on the regex itself, more on the greedy/non-greedy part. You're right of course

Answer (score -1):

```
re.compile('/<test/>(\w\s)+?/<br/>')
```

Notice the `?` after `(\w\s)+`

For more detail, see http://docs.python.org/howto/regex.html#greedy-versus-non-greedy